# Error al crear un Schema con un campo de tipo file en NodeJs

Tags: json, nodejs, angular, archivo

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;


const empleado_schema = new Schema({
    dni:{type:String,required:true, unique:true},
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    apellidos:{type:String, required:true},
    departamento:{type:String, required:true},
    sueldo:{type:String, required:true},
    fecha_nacimiento:{type:Date, required:true},
    imagen_perfil:{type:File,required:true}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('tbEmpleadoss',empleado_schema);
```

Todo va bien hasta que inserto el campo **imagen_perfil** el cual me arroja el siguiente error:

```
 imagen_perfil:{type:File,required:true}
                    ^
```

ReferenceError: File is not defined

Comment: Hola @jose angel, el motivo del error es porque el 'type' que indicas no existe para 'Mongoose'. Aquí puedes verificar los tipos de variables que acepta Mongoose (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html). Saludos

Comment: hola es exactamente lo que dice @planta4 aunque puedes crear tipos personalizados https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html